# How to use "cmp" to compare two binaries and find all the byte offsets where they differ?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would love some help with a Bash script loop that will show all the differences between two binary files, using just

```
cmp file1 file2
```

It only shows the first change I would like to use cmp because it gives a offset an a line number of where each change is but if you think there's a better command I'm open to it :) thanks

Comment: The offset is valid, but the line number will not be valid when comparing binary files, as they have no concept of lines (only text have lines).

Comment: Yeah I understand, in this case I use the line number to reference to a hexdump of the binary so I read whats around the different offset :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think `cmp -l file1 file2` might do what you want. From the manpage:

```
-l  --verbose
      Output byte numbers and values of all differing bytes.
```

The output is a table of the offset, the byte value in file1 and the value in file2 for all differing bytes. It looks like this:

```
4531  66  63
4532  63  65
4533  64  67
4580  72  40
4581  40  55
[...]
```

So the first difference is at offset 4531, where file1's **<strike>decimal</strike>** [**octal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmp_(Unix)) byte value is 66 and file2's is 63.

Comment: +1: this is 'the way to do it', but the problem with it is that `cmp` does not look for inserted or deleted material; it just checks 'if the byte at offset N in file1 the same as the byte at offset N in file2; if yes, then print nothing, else print difference'.  So the files have to be very similar (eg, just some bytes in the Unix timestamp when the object files were compiled - which is built into some object files) but the rest needs to be the same.  Add 3 bytes to a constant string and everything after that is different.

Comment: Thanks heaps this is just what I wanted, i try that in the past but I did know the the numbers on the side where the offsets :) Thanks heaps!

Comment: I've edited the answer by add a correction about format of the bytes that differ. This is a not so well documented feature of cmp. I hope that the edit is appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

**Method that works for single byte addition/deletion**

```
diff <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v file1) \
     <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v file2)
```

Generate a test case with a single removal of byte 64:

```
for i in `seq 128`; do printf "%02x" "$i"; done | xxd -r -p > file1
for i in `seq 128`; do if [ "$i" -ne 64 ]; then printf "%02x" $i; fi; done | xxd -r -p > file2
```

Output:

```
64d63
<  40
```

If you also want to see the ASCII version of the character:

```
bdiff() (
  f() (
    od -An -tx1c -w1 -v "$1" | paste -d '' - -
  )
  diff <(f "$1") <(f "$2")
)

bdiff file1 file2
```

Output:

```
64d63
<   40   @
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

I prefer `od` over `xxd` because:

- it [is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html), `xxd` is not (comes with Vim)
- has the `-An` to remove the address column without `awk`.

Command explanation:

- `-An` removes the address column. This is important otherwise all lines would differ after a byte addition / removal.
- `-w1` puts one byte per line, so that diff can consume it. It is crucial to have one byte per line, or else every line after a deletion would become out of phase and differ. Unfortunately, this is not POSIX, but present in GNU.
- `-tx1` is the representation you want, change to any possible value, as long as you keep 1 byte per line.
- `-v` prevents asterisk repetition abbreviation `*` which might interfere with the diff
- `paste -d '' - -` joins every two lines. We need it because the hex and ASCII go into separate adjacent lines. Taken from: [Concatenating every other line with the next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987257/concatenating-every-other-line-with-the-next)
- we use parenthesis `()` to define `bdiff` instead of `{}` to limit the scope of the inner function `f`, see also: [How to define a function inside another function in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426077/how-to-define-a-function-inside-another-function-in-bash)

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59849/diff-binary-files-of-different-sizes

Comment: This has the inherent flaw that it will not stream the data but load everything into RAM, meaning you will need at least 2 - 3 times the size of the files as memory, which most binary diff tools use. The only one I found that doesn't behave like this is xdelta3...

Comment: @Izzy add it to an answer showing to use it and why and get upvotes :-)

Comment: Sadly, to my knowledge, it can't. At least not the kind you'd expect. It produces VCDIFF output, which is a highly compressed binary delta. So you can just diff, patch and few the command structure. My comment was more of a "be aware that this answer will blow your main memory with a 5GB file"

Comment: @Izzy OK! Good to know nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

The more efficient workaround I've found is to translate binary files to some form of text using `od`.

Then any flavour of `diff` works fine.

Comment: Yep, it really depends on what the OP wants to do with the diff. A diff of a hexdump is probably of more value for humans, while a `cmp` may be easier for programs to parse/use.