# Defining bash function body using parenthesis instead of braces

Tags: bash, bash-function

This script demonstrates defining a bash function with parenthesis
verses with braces.  The parenthesis have the nice effect of making
environment variables created in the function "local", I guess
because the function body is executed as a sub-shell.  The output is:

```
A=something
A=
B=something
B=something
```

The question is if this is allowed syntax for defining a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() (
    export A=something
    echo A=$A
)

bar() {
    export B=something
    echo B=$B
}

foo
echo A=$A
bar
echo B=$B
```

Comment: wrong guess. These variables appear to be local, because this [compound command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar#compound_commands) is executed in a separate group (context), NOT a subshell!!

Comment: @Florian Bash and POSIX call it a "subshell environment", maybe that's what he meant. But true: not a new process.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that syntax is allowed.  As described in the [`bash` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), the definition of a bash function is:

```
[ function ] name () compound-command [redirection]
```

Some more description (also from the man page):

> The body of the function is the compound command `compound-command`.  That command is usually a list of commands between `{` and `}`, but may be  any  command listed under **Compound Commands** above.

`()` and `{}` enclosed lists are compound commands.  The full list (again from the man page, just edited down to a simple list):

> A compound command is one of the following:
>
> ```
> (list)
> { list; }
> ((expression))
> [[expression]]
> for name [ in word ] ; do list ; done
> for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done
> select name [ in word ] ; do list ; done
> case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac
> if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
> while list; do list; done
> until list; do list; done
> ```

Comment: Thanks for that. I notice this fails:

   foo() ( export A=something ; echo A=$A )
   bar() { export B=something ; echo B=$B }

This works:

   foo() ( export A=something ; echo A=$A ; )
   bar() { export B=something ; echo B=$B ; }

Yet so does this:

   ( echo Hi ; echo Bye )

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand - are you asking something about the semicolons?

Comment: For examples, see also the Code-Golf FAQ answer about defining functions using `f()(CODE)` instead of `f(){ CODE;}` [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41201).

Answer (score 5):

Both are valid, and as Carl mentioned any *compound command* can also be used, e.g.:

```
$ f() if [ "$1" = 'a' ]; then echo 'equals a'; fi
$ f a
equals a
$ f b
$
```

POSIX 7 **2.9.5 Function Definition Command** http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05:

> The format of a function definition command is as follows:
>
> fname() compound-command[io-redirect ...]
>
> [...] The argument compound-command represents a compound command, as described in Compound Commands.

Then **2.9.4 Compound Commands** http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04:

> (compound-list) [...] Variable assignments and built-in commands that affect the environment shall not remain in effect after the list finishes.
>
> { compound-list;} Execute compound-list in the current process environment.

The semantics are the same as using `()` without a function definition: it does not create a new process, but gets executed in what POSIX and Bash call a "subshell environment".