# Achieve Local Function

Tags: bash, shell, sh

What I want trying to achieve is to create a **local function within a function**. At the same time, the **local function will not overwrite the outer function**. Below is an example of a simple function and a nested function with argument to illustrate my problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() #<------------------------------- same function name
{
    echo "Overall Usage"
}

function_A()
{
    usage() #<--------------------------- same function name
    {
        echo "function_A Usage"
    }

    for i in "$@"; do
        case $i in
            --help)
                usage
                shift
                ;;
            *)
                echo "flag provided but not defined: ${i%%=*}"
                echo "See '$0 --help'."
                exit 0
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

function_A --help
usage
```

Here is output.

```
function_A Usage
function_A Usage
```

But what I want is

```
function_A Usage
Overall Usage
```

Is is possible to achieve without change their (functions) name and order? Please?

Note: I tried the `local usage()` but it seem not applicable to function.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Bash does not support local functions, but depending on your specific script and architecture you can control the scope of your function name through subshells.

By replacing the `{..}`  with `(..)` in your definition, you'll get the output you want. The new definition of `usage` will be limited to the function, but so will e.g. any changes to variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() 
{
    echo "Overall Usage"
}

function_A()
(                  # <-- Use subshell
    usage()
    {
        echo "function_A Usage"
    }

    for i in "$@"; do
        case $i in
            --help)
                usage
                shift
                ;;
            *)
                echo "flag provided but not defined: ${i%%=*}"
                echo "See '$0 --help'."
                exit 0
            ;;
        esac
    done
)

function_A --help
usage
```

Comment: Could you please improve this answer by adding some link explaining what is `(..)` (e.g. man subshell) and when we must use it? Thanks.

Comment: @4wk_ The body of a function can be any [compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Compound-Commands.html).  This is most often a curly braces `{...}` [grouping command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html), but can also be a `(...)` grouping command as well.  The difference between `{...}` and `(...)` is that `(...)` runs the commands in a *subshell*.  [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802082/2668666) explains this syntax further.

Comment: @jrahhali Thank you for this explanation and the provided links ;)

Comment: The other way is to use *uniq* function names: `usage() { echo Overall usage;};: ...;myfunc() { myfunc_usage() { echo Myfunc usage;};}`, which could even be *unset*: `unset -f myfunc_usage`. This is the only was to retrieve environment change at main level.

Answer (score 5):

From `man bash`:

> **Compound Commands**
>
> A compound command is one of the following:
>
> (list) list is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below). Variable assignments  and  builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes.  The return status is the exit status of list.
>   ...

1. Suppose we have test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

topFunction1() {
    # start subshell
    (


        innerFunction1() {
            echo "innerFunction1"
        }

        echo "topFunction1 can call $(innerFunction1) from within the subshell"


    )
    # end subshell


    innerFunction2() {
        echo "innerFunction2"
    }
}

topFunction2() {
    echo "topFunction2"
}
```

2. Now let's do `source test.sh`.

The following command is successful:

`topFunction2`

The following commands fail:

`innerFunction1`

`innerFunction2`

3. Now if we do `topFunction1` we'll get an output containing `innerFunction1` output:

   > topFunction1 can call innerFunction1 from within the subshell

At this point the following commands are successful:

`topFunction1`

`topFunction2`

`innerFunction2`

One can notice that now `innerFunction2` it's visible globally after the call to `topFunction1`.
However `innerFunction1` it's still 'hidden' for calls out of the subshell and this is what you probably want.

Another call to `innerFunction1` will fail.

Answer (score 4):

To expand upon [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34985567/117471)'s answer:

```
$ function zz() (:;)

$ declare -f zz

zz ()
{
    ( : )
}
```

You can see that defining a function with parenthesis instead of braces is just shorthand for encasing the whole interior of a function with parenthesis. The function actually identifies in its long form.

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: I may have been compelled to give this answer just so that I could make a reference to [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34985567/117471). I may have made this comment for the same reason.

Comment: The semicolon is not needed in the parenthesis form. In fact it could be defined `zz()(:)`.

Comment: @ingydotnet not only "could be defined", but you will see by the output of the `declare -f`, that is how the optimizer resolves it. ;-)

Comment: The real question is, what (if any) are the performance implications?