# Renaming functions locally inside other functions

Tags: bash, function

Have written a function named `linge`.  How can I use a replacement for the function name inside another function, locally using a different name such as `lg`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply define `lg` to call `ligne`.

```
function otherFunc() {
    function lg() { ligne "$@"; }
    lg 1 2 3
}
```

Note that this will define a global function `lg`, too. See [Achieve Local Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985408/achieve-local-function) for how to work around this by defining the function to run in a subshell.

```
function otherFunc() (
    function lg() { ligne "$@"; }
    lg 1 2 3
)
```

But if you do this, any variable assignments done in the function will also not be visible outside the function.

Comment: Have studied the link where the function is defined in a subshell. Can I use a subshell within a normal function using `{...}`?

Comment: Subshells require `(...)`

Comment: I meant to say, a subshell with `(...)` within a normal function defined using `{...}`.

Comment: Of course. You can use that inside the function just like you can anywhere else.

Comment: I have put a solution up.

Comment: I am quite unsure about writing a function that can evaluate itself to `0` or `1`.  Does one use `return 0` and `return 0` at the end or does one use `echo "0"` and `echo "1"` instead?

Comment: @Angio `return` sets the exit status of the function, which you can check in the caller using `if` or `$?`. `echo` writes output, which you can capture using `$(command)`. It depends on what the purpose of the function is.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you include "$@" as arguments to 'lg' in the declaration `function lg() { ligne "$@"; }`. Are the parameters "$@" taken from the parameters coming through `otherFunc`?

Comment: Yes, of course. How else would `lg` get the parameters?

Comment: My assumption has been that "$@" in `lg` are tho parameter arguments for `lg`, rather than the parameter arguments set by `otherFunc`.  The parameters to `otherFunc` could very well be different than the parameters to `lg`.

Comment: Inside `lg`, `$@` is the arguments to `lg`, not `otherFunc`.

Comment: Every function has its own set of `$1, $2, $3, $@`

Comment: Good.  I follow and it is as it should be.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have had a go using a subshell inside the function

```
myfunc ()
{
 val="Fred" 
 (
  function lg() { linge "$@"; }

  lg "$src" && printf '%s\n' "No src used"
  lg "$dst" && printf '%s\n' "No dst used"
  val="Joe"
 )
 echo "val: $val"
 echo "More commands follow"

}
```

Running the function `myfunc` gives

```
val: Fred
```

The above means that `val="Joe"` is local to the sub-shell.  Would it be possible to got some variable inside the sub-shell that can be transferred outside the sub-shell (which will be used as a flag) for use by `myfunc`.