# assign local variable from function in linux bash a new value

Tags: bash, function, scope, global-variables

I have a `linux bash` script with a function:

```
myfunctiona () 
{
  local MYVAR1="one"
  local MYVAR2="two"
  echo $MYVAR1
  # The line beneath is the line in question!
  local MYVAR1=$MYVAR1$MYVAR2       
}
```

When I want to give the `LOCAL` variable `MYVAR1` in the function `myfunctiona` a new value, do I have to write

```
local MYVAR1=$MYVAR1$MYVAR2
```

or can I also write

```
MYVAR1=$MYVAR1$MYVAR2
```

With the second line without "local" do I create a global variable with the same name?

Comment: You have to give `MYVAR1="$MYVAR1$MYVAR2";`

Comment: Why not just try it out with echo :-) ? POSIX way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597697/posix-compliant-way-to-scope-variables-to-a-function-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Once you've defined a local variable you can assign it normally, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunctiona () 
{
  local MYVAR1="one"
  local MYVAR2="two"
  echo $MYVAR1
  # The line beneath is the line in question!
  local MYVAR1=$MYVAR1$MYVAR2    
  MYVAR1="FOO"
  echo $MYVAR1   
}

myfunctiona
echo "global" $MYVAR1
```

which gives the output:

```
one
FOO
global
```

- As you can see attempting to access the variable from global scope returns null

HTH

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do it would be:

```
MYVAR1="${MYVAR1}${MYVAR2}"
```

The braces are usually used when you concatenate variables. [Use quotes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

The variable is still local since you reassigned its value within the scope of the function.
An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_myFunction()
{
    local var_1="one"
    local var_2="two"
    local -g var_3="three" # The -g switch makes a local variable a global variable
    var_4="four" # This will be global since we didn't mark it as a local variable from the start

    var_1="${var_1}${var_2}"

    echo "Inside function var_1=${var_1}"
    echo "Inside function var_2=${var_2}"
    echo "Inside function var_3=${var_3}"
    echo "Inside function var_4=${var_4}"
}

_myFunction

echo "Outside function var_1=${var_1}"
echo "Outside function var_2=${var_2}"
echo "Outside function var_3=${var_3}"
echo "Outside function var_4=${var_4}"
```

This results in:

```
$ ./script
Inside function var_1=onetwo
Inside function var_2=two
Inside function var_3=three
Inside function var_4=four
Outside function var_1=
Outside function var_2=
Outside function var_3=three
Outside function var_4=four
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give this way, but as Ube said for concatenation you need to give like that -

```
MYVAR1="$MYVAR1$MYVAR2";
```

Even this works for concatenation

Comment: Are you asking about the local and global status