# Struggling with while loop with two conditions and a for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to learn how to use arrays in bash. I'm writing a script that asks the user for three numbers and figures out what the biggest number is. I want the script to force the user to enter only numeric values. Furthermore, I want the three numbers should be different. I'm using an array to store user input. This is what I have so far:

```
## declare variables
order=("first" "second" "third")
answers=()
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

numbersonly() {
        if [[ ! $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "${RED}$1 is not a valid number.${NC}"
        else
            answers+=("$input")
            break
        fi
}

inarray(){
    for e in ${answers[@]}; do
    if [[ $1 == $e ]]; then
    echo "${RED}Warning.${NC}"
    fi
    done
}

readnumber(){
for i in {1..3}; do
j=$(awk "BEGIN { print $i-1 }")
    while read -p "Enter the ${order[$j]} number: " input ; do      
    inarray $input
    numbersonly $input
    done
done
}

displayanswers(){
echo "Your numbers are: ${answers[@]}"
}

biggestnumber(){

if (( ${answers[0]} >= ${answers[1]} )); then
        biggest=${answers[0]}
        else
        biggest=${answers[1]}
        fi
if (( $biggest <= ${answers[2]} )); then
        biggest=${answers[2]}
        fi  
echo "The biggest number is: $biggest"
}

main(){
readnumber
displayanswers
biggestnumber
}

main
```

Right now, I can get the script to display a warning when the user enters a number that was previously entered, but I can't seem to find the proper syntax to stay in the while loop if the user input has already been entered. Thoughts?

Comment: Checking whether a value is already in an array, your more efficient approach is to index by the values as your keys. That is, `values[$i]=1` lets you check `${values[$i]}` as an O(1) operation without needing to iterate.

Comment: Beyond that, though, there's frankly too much code here to tell what your *intended* flow control is at a glance. Can you build a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code that demonstrates the problem you're asking about (and describing explicitly how its current and intended behavior differ)? If you can reproduce your issue with only one loop, there's no need for five functions and a bunch of globally-scoped assignments cluttering up the question.

Comment: One thing, your call to displayanswers has an extra 'h' when you call it in main().  And biggestnumber should be on another line right?

Comment: @Nic3500 yep. I changed it

Comment: I am with @CharlesDuffy, you need to look at simplifying the code to the base of what you are stuck on.  I also agree that you need to look at minimising your global variables in your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it. My problem was twofold: 1) I didn't realize that if you have a for loop nested in a while loop, you'll need two break statements to exit the while loop; 2) having two functions within the same while loop made it hard to control what was happening. By merging inarray() and numbersonly() into a new function, I solved the double conditional issue. The new function looks like this:

```
testing(){
for item in ${answers[*]}
do
    test "$item" == "$1" && { inlist="yes"; break; } || inlist="no"
done

if [[ $inlist == "yes" ]]; then
echo "${RED}$1 is already in list.${NC}"
else
        if [[ ! $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "${RED}$1 is not a valid number.${NC}"
        else
            answers+=("$input")
            break
        fi
fi
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Without much study here is what leapt off the screen to me follows. Beware I haven't actually tested it... debugging is an exercise left to the student.

Recommend using newer "function" definitions as you can declare local variables. () definitions do not allow localized variables.

```
function inarray
{
    local e;   #don't muck up any variable e in caller
 ...
}
```

To calculate values avoid extra awk and use `j=$(( i - 1 ));`

`biggestnumber` should likely use a loop.

Overall comment:

```
nummax=3;  #maximum value defined in just one place

# loop this way... showing optional {} trick for marking larger loops
for (( n = 0; n < nummax; ++n )); do
{
     nx=$(( 1 + n ));   #1 based index
} done;
```

Hint: should stop input loop once all input present. Could also add:

```
    if [ "" == "${input:-}" ]; then break;
```

```
for (( a = 0; a < ${#answer[*]}; ++a )); do
```

Note the extensive use of double quotes to avoid syntax errors if the variable value is empty or contains many shell metacharacters, like spaces. I can't tell you how many bug reports I've fixed by adding the quotes to existing code.

[[ ... ]] expressions use file name tests, not regular expressions.  The closest you can get to `[[ ! $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];` is using `[[ "$1" != [0-9]* ]] && [[ "$1" != *[^0-9]* ]]`. 
But I suspect **`! expr >/dev/null "$i" : '[0-9][0-9]*$';`** is more what you want as "expr" does use regular expressions. Don't enclose in []s. Used [0-9][0-9]* rather than [0-9]+ as "+" has given me mixed successes across all dialects of UNIX regular expressions.

Comment: `typeset` and your function definition style is old-school Korn shell.  What you say about the different styles of function declarations and local variables is true for Korn shell but **not** true for Bash.  In ksh you can get different results from a function depending on how it is declared, that is not the case in bash.  Bash supports `typeset` for backwards compatibility but `local` (or `declare`) is preferred.

Comment: Oh, and your example `if` statement is missing a `then`.

Comment: The `+` quantifier is Extended Regular Expressions (egrep, awk, Perl, Python, Ruby, Java, bash, etc, etc), not Basic Regular Expressions (vanilla grep and sed).  That's probably why you sometimes have problems with it.  Modern versions of grep and sed have options to allow EREs.  Korn shell has alternative syntax for both.

Comment: In addition to @cdarke's comments, you don't need `{...}` to put multiple commands in a loop; the body of a `for` loop is already an arbitrary list of commands. There's no need to define `nx`, because you can simply initialize `n=1` and loop while `n <= nummax`.

Comment: Yest to above, edited if (thanks @cdarke), but unfortunately sometimes I need to edit old-school legacy scripts running on old shells so I like stuff that works everywhere. And this includes legacy ksh to current ksh.

Comment: @Gilbert, the `function` keyword makes your code incompatible with baseline-POSIX shells such as dash -- and since it results in different behavior between ksh and bash, it *reduces* portability by creating room for cross-shell incompatibility (reducing the applicability of tests on one shell to tests on another) even where it *is* supported.

Comment: By the way, sadly, neither `local` or `typeset` are part of the POSIX standard.  `local` is often an alias for `typeset` in ksh, but that's non-standard.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597697/posix-compliant-way-to-scope-variables-to-a-function-in-a-shell-script

Comment: @cdarke: I've seen so many shells and shell incompatibilities over years it drives me nuts. Somehow I've missed using dash with any seriousness. Will look into it more now.