# Avoiding temporary files while iterating over pipeline results

Tags: bash

I've created the function to display interfaces and IP's per interface

```
network() {
iplst() {
ip a show "$i" | grep -oP "inet\s+\K[\w./]+" | grep -v 127
}
ip ntable | grep -oP "dev\s+\K[\w./]+"| grep -v lo | sort -u >> inf_list
netlist="inf_list"
while read -r i
do
infd=$i
   paste <(echo -e $i) <(iplst)
 done < $netlist
}
```

Current output:

```
ens32   10.0.0.2/24
        10.0.0.4/24
        10.0.0.20/24
ens33   192.168.1.3/24
ens34   192.168.0.2/24
ens35   192.168.2.149/24
```

but would like to avoid creation of temp files, 
would appreciate suggestions

Comment: Are you sure you want to *nest* your functions? See, for example, [How to define a function inside another function in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8426077/3266847)

Comment: Why are you using `paste` when only one line is being processed at a time?

Comment: Also, this code is missing functionality needed for others to be able to test it. For instance, `iplst` is completely undefined. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Charles Duffy  Because one interface has one interface name and may have 10 IP's,  and I need them to be displayed in columns as it is now

Comment: "As it is now" -- nobody but you can see that, because your code isn't complete enough for anyone but you to run it.

Comment: Ahh; better. Relying on `i` as a global variable is rather... *unfortunate*, by the way -- better to flag it local and pass it around as an explicit argument.

Comment: BTW, need I say that `grep -v 127` is a bad idea? `10.1.0.127` is very much an IP address that can exist without loopback involvement.

Comment: it does, but it's nothing informative about it, it does exists by default.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , on an other though, you'r right,  I'll probably will implement a filter to ignore it only if it is described in lo,  thanks

Comment: The change I made in my answer -- filtering out `127` only at the *start* of an address, and not in any other position -- is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, temporary files can be replaced with *process substitution*. For instance, to avoid the `inf_list` temporary file, one can generate its contents with an `inf_list` *function*:

```
build_inf_list() {
  ip ntable | grep -oP "dev\s+\K[\w./]+"| grep -v lo | sort -u
}

iplst() {
  ip a show "$1" | grep -oP "inet\s+\K[\w./]+" | egrep -v '^127'
}

while read -r i; do
  paste <(printf '%s\n' "$i") <(iplst "$i")
done < <(build_inf_list)
```

---

Some notes:

- Passing (and using) explicit arguments makes it much more obvious to a reader than relying on globals set elsewhere in your code, and reduce the chances that functions added in the future will stomp on variable names you're depending on.
- Using process substitution, `<(...)`, is replaced with a filename which, when read from, will return the stdout of the command `...`; thus, since what you're writing to your temporary file comes from such a command, you can simply replace the temporary file with a process substitution invocation.
- Any shell where `echo -e` does not print `-e` on its output is [defying black-letter POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). While `bash` is noncompliant in this manner *by default*, it's not noncompliant *consistently* -- if the `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are both set, then bash complies with the letter of the standard. It's much safer to use `printf`, which is far more robustly defined. See also the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the linked standard document, which explains how BSD and AT&T UNIX have traditionally incompatible versions of `echo`, and thus why the POSIX standard is so loose in the behavior it mandates.

Answer (score 0):

Final result, thanks @Charles Duffy

```
#!/bin/bash
build_inf_list() {
  ip ntable | grep -oP "dev\s+\K[\w./]+"| grep -v lo | sort -u
}
iplst() {
if [ "$1" = "lo" ]; then
  ip a show "$1" | grep -oP "inet\s+\K[\w./]+" | grep -v '^127'
else
  ip a show "$1" | grep -oP "inet\s+\K[\w./]+"
fi
}

while read -r i; do
  paste <(printf '%s\n' "$i") <(iplst "$i")
done < <(build_inf_list)
```

edited

Comment: As an aside -- `==` isn't actually guaranteed to be supported in `[ ]`; the string comparison operator that's mandated by the POSIX standard is just `=`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: (There's still the outstanding bug about filtering out addresses on `lo` that contain `127` in something other than starting position, too -- if you had `1.2.3.127` assigned to `lo`, you probably don't want `grep -v 127` to be taking it out as if it had been `127.0.0.1`; making that filter `grep -v '^127'` avoids the issue).